# Accessing nested ActionController::Parameters showing wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

My feature_params method returns a hash like->

```
[40] pry(#<FeaturesController>)> feature_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"dola", "desc"=>"none", "category"=>"Backlog", "feature_token_id"=>"950743", "tasks_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"newtask", "completed"=>"0", "user_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

And naturally >

```
[41] pry(#<FeaturesController>)> feature_params[:tasks_attributes]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"newtask", "completed"=>"0", "user_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

But when I try to access the attributes of `tasks_attributes` then It fails->

```
[42] pry(#<FeaturesController>)> feature_params[:tasks_attributes][:user_id]
=> nil
```

What is the way to capture the values of the nested hash in ActionController::Parameters  other than `feature_params[:tasks_attributes][:user_id]`

Comment: As per the data you have shown the correct way to access `user_id` is `feature_params[:tasks_attributes]['0'][:user_id]` because that's the way your params Hash is structured. Still you can try `feature_params.to_unsafe_h` to see your Hash in plain format and you should be able to see why `feature_params[:tasks_attributes][:user_id]` didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem in `"0"`, try next:

```
[42] pry(#<FeaturesController>)> feature_params[:tasks_attributes]["0"][:user_id]
```